# PHP: Check if two random words are not the same

Tags: php

I am working on a nickname generator tool. I have two .json files with the arrays of the first and second syllables.

First syllable = beginning of the word.

Second syllable = ending of the word.

Here is how the tool generates a random nickname:

```
$name = ucwords($first_syllable[rand(0, count($first_syllable) - 1)] . $second_syllable[rand(0, count($second_syllable) - 1)]);
```

This works fine, but now I need to check that first syllable is not the same as the second one.

For example, I have first syllable "Dal" in the array, and I have a second syllable "Dal" too. I do not want the tool to generate "Daldal". That is why, I need to check if the first syllable is NOT the same as the second syllable.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if they are same or not -

```
$name1 = $first_syllable[rand(0, count($first_syllable) - 1)]; 
$name2 = $second_syllable[rand(0, count($second_syllable) - 1)];

if (strtolower($name1) !== strtolower($name2)) {
    $name = ucwords($name1 . $name2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$firstS = ucwords($first_syllable[rand(0, count($first_syllable) - 1)]);
$secondS = ucwords($second_syllable[rand(0, count($second_syllable) - 1)]);

if($firstS != $secondS)
  $name = $firstS.$secondS;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to store selected values in variables and then loop until they are different.

The loop will make sure your two values are different.

An example of code (not tested):

```
<?php
$second_syllable_value = '';
$first_syllable_value = '';
while ($second_syllable_value == $first_syllable_value)
{
    $first_syllable_value = $second_syllable[rand(0, count($second_syllable) - 1)];
    $second_syllable_value = $second_syllable[rand(0, count($second_syllable) - 1)];
}
?>
```

Be careful of the **length of your arrays** because you can end up in an infinite loop.